# Error while deploying laravel app to heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

I was testing how to deploy an laravel app to heroku so i just created a simple app in laravel and followed this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel.

At first I had a problem with heroku not recognizing that my app was an php application so I added a mostly empty package.json in order for heroku to detect it as explained in this guide https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

Now it detects it but it still can't be deployed and shows this error:

```
Counting objects: 127, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
Writing objects: 100% (127/127), 236.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 127 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0) 
remote: Compressing source files... done. 
remote: Building source: 
remote:  
remote: -----> PHP app detected 
remote: -----> Bootstrapping... 
remote: -----> Installing platform packages... 
remote:  
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to install system packages. 
remote:         
remote:        Your platform requirements (for runtimes and extensions) could 
remote:        not be resolved to an installable set of dependencies, or a             
remote:        repository was unreachable. 
remote:         
remote:        Full error information from installation attempt: 
remote:         
remote:        > Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions 
remote:        >  
remote:        >                                                               
remote:        >   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]            
remote:        >   The 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cedar-14/packages.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden   
remote:        >             
remote:        >  
remote:        > install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]... 
remote:        >  
remote:         
remote:        Please verify that all requirements for runtime versions in     
remote:        'composer.lock' are compatible with the list below, and ensure 
remote:        all required extensions are available for the desired runtimes. 
remote:         
remote:        For reference, the following runtimes are currently available: 
remote:         
remote:        PHP:   
remote:        HHVM:  
remote:         
remote:        For a list of supported runtimes & extensions on Heroku, please 
remote:        refer to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support     
remote:  
remote:  !  Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app. 
remote:  
remote:  !     Push failed 
remote: Verifying deploy... 
remote:  
remote: !   Push rejected to nameless-peak-52308. 
remote:  To https://git.heroku.com/nameless-peak-52308.git  
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nameless-peak-52308.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cedar-14/packages.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

This means you need to set the permissions to public for this file/folder in AWS. I'm guessing you're logged in and you can access it fine, but Heroku can't view it because of the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by configuring heroku with this:

```
   heroku config:set HEROKU_PHP_PLATFORM_REPOSITORIES="https://heroku-v8js.s3.amazonaws.com/dist-cedar-14-stable/packages.json"
```

as explained by https://github.com/phpv8/heroku-v8js

Answer (score 0):

It can be by the composer, use `composer update` and then add it using`git add .` then upload it to the heroku server with `git push heroku master`